# Python 2D array replace value by NaN when other array is NaN

Tags: python, arrays, nan, mask

I have 2 arrays:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([[np.nan,np.nan,0],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
B = np.zeros((len(A),len(A[0])))
```

For every NaN in A, I would like to replace the zero in B at the corresponding indices by np.nan. How can I do that ? I tried with masks but couldn't make it work.

```
B = np.ma.masked_where(np.isnan(A) == True, np.nan)
```

In reality I am working with bigger arrays (582x533) so I don't want to do it by hand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `np.isnan(A)` directly:

```
B = np.zeros_like(A)
B[np.isnan(A)] = np.nan
```

`np.where` is useful for when you want to construct `B` directly:

```
B = np.where(np.isnan(A), np.nan, 0)
```

Comment: @user1740577. Your answer is fine, but you sort of conflated two approaches that are simpler by themselves. I appreciate the endorsement.

Answer (score 2):

You can create [`np.zeros`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html) with `A.shape` then use [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) like below:

*(this approach construct B two times)*

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> A = np.array([[np.nan,np.nan,0],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
>>> B = np.zeros(A.shape)
>>> B = np.where(np.isnan(A) , np.nan, B)
>>> B
array([[nan, nan,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

Comment: You really don't need to recreate B a second time

Comment: @MadPhysicist OK, Understand ;)